# Load a div or href link at the end of jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'want to design jquery progress bar[PB] which when completes 100%, the PB should be hidden and a 'HTML href link' to be displayed rather then the alert box as shown in the demo, so that on clicking the link i want to redirect to another page.

the demo of the progress bar can be found below..

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Graphical-Circular-Timer-with-jQuery-CSS3-pietimer/

the code below is what i've tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('#timer').pietimer({
      timerSeconds: 10,
      color: '#234',
      fill: false,
      showPercentage: true,
      callback: function() {
            $("input[name='btn']").click(function() {
            $("#parent").html("<div>content of the div</div>");
        });
      }
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div id="menu">
<div id="timer" style="margin-top:100px;">
<div id="parent">       
</div>
 <form>
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Button" />
 </form>
</div>
```

please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/dXVRS/)

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="timer"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $(function () {
  var timer = $('#timer');
  timer.pietimer({
      timerSeconds: 1,
      color: '#234',
      fill: false,
      showPercentage: true,
      callback: function () {
          timer.hide();
          $('#parent').append("<a href='http://goo.gl'>Link </a>")
      }
  });
});
```

Modify it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly as I wanted. Can i use any custom image as progress bar background rather then the 'color: '#234''..

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with HTML structure. you missed closing tag for `timer div`. I have corrected the same and created [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/GY8XD/1/) for you

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly as I wanted. Can i use any custom image as progress bar background rather then the 'color: '#234''..